# Java - Exception PropertyUtilsBean.setIndexedProperty

Tags: apache-commons-beanutils

```
public class TestBean {
    private String[] array;

    public String[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }

    public void setArray(String[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }
}

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

public class BeanUtilTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestBean bean = new TestBean();
        try {
            BeanUtils.setProperty(bean, "array[0]", "zero");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

While running the code the following exception is getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setIndexedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1414)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:1016)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.setProperty(BeanUtils.java:313)
at BeanUtilTest.main(BeanUtilTest.java:10)
```

The array size will be increase while run time. So I don't want as a fixed size array. Array size should be defined at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the array or set the array using

```
BeanUtils.setProperty(bean, "array", array);
```

and then use following operation to set the value

```
BeanUtils.setProperty(bean, "array[0]", "zero");
```

Array size will not increase during runtime